# Friend function not working (syntax errors)

Tags: c++, friend-function

I'm new to C++, I've never implemented a friend function before. But I've been given a specific friend function to implement that goes as follows `std​::​ostream &​operator ​<< (​std​::​ostream ​&out, ​const ​Library ​&lib);`. I assumed that this was supposed to go in the header file for the Library class, but for some reason, ostream, out, and lib are all raising syntax errors. I also don't really understand what is trying to be a friend of what based on this line of code. Sorry for the vagueness of my question, but again I really don't know much about friend functions. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Library.h

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef ASS1_LIBRARY_H
#define ASS1_LIBRARY_H

class Library {

    private:
        static const int MAX = 10;
        std::string BookList[MAX];
        std::string libraryName;
        int length;

    public:
        explicit Library(const std::string &name);

        // Add a new book,
        // return true for success, false if book already in library
        bool AddBook(const std::string &name);

        // Remove a book
        // return true for success, false if book not in library
        bool RemoveBook(const std::string &name);

        // List all books in library
        void ListAllBooks() const;

        // Return true if book in library, false otherwise
        bool IsInLibrary(const std::string &name) const;

        std::string getLibraryName();

};

//friend function
std​::​ostream &​operator ​<< (​std​::​ostream ​&out, ​const ​Library ​&lib);

#endif //ASS1_LIBRARY_H
```

Library.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

Library::Library(const string &name) {
    libraryName = name;
    length = 0;
}

bool Library::AddBook(const string &name) {
    if(IsInLibrary(name) || length >= MAX) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        length++;
        BookList[length - 1] = name;
        return true;
    }
}

bool Library::RemoveBook(const std::string &name) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length) {
        if(BookList[counter] == name) {
            BookList[counter] = "";
            length--;
            while(counter < length) {
                BookList[counter] = BookList[counter + 1];
                BookList[counter + 1] = "";
                counter++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return false;
}

void Library::ListAllBooks() const {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length) {
        cout << BookList[counter];
        if(counter != length - 1) {
            cout << "," << endl;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

bool Library::IsInLibrary(const std::string &name) const {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length) {
        if(BookList[counter] == name) {
            return true;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return false;
}

string Library::getLibraryName() {
    return libraryName;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Library.h"

int main() {
    Library execute("MyLibrary");
    execute.AddBook("Book 1");
    execute.AddBook("Book 2");
    execute.AddBook("Book 3");
    execute.AddBook("Book 4");
    execute.AddBook("Book 5");
    execute.AddBook("Book 6");
    execute.AddBook("Book 7");
    execute.AddBook("Book 8");
    execute.AddBook("Book 9");
    execute.AddBook("Book 10");
    execute.RemoveBook("Book 3");
    execute.RemoveBook("Book 5");
    execute.RemoveBook("Book 10");
    execute.RemoveBook("B");
    execute.ListAllBooks();
    std::cout << execute.getLibraryName() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(ass1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(ass1 main.cpp Library.cpp Library.h)
```

Comment: Let's ask the duck.

Comment: You didn't actually tell, within your `Library` class, that a friend function exists.

Comment: Compiler doesn't understand comments.

Comment: FWIW, a common idiom is to have the `operator<<(ostream & out, const Foo & obj)` friend function defined right inside the header, possibly `inline`-qualified and just be `{ obj.print(out); return out; }`. With the actual work in a regular `print` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make the function a friend of the class, so that it can access the private members of the class.

To do that the function has to be declared as a friend within the definition of the class itself. (The class gets to choose its friends.)

So you would need to put this inside the `class Library { };`:

```
friend std​::​ostream &​operator ​<< (​std​::​ostream ​&out, ​const ​Library ​&lib);
```

Then you have two choices. You could actually define the function right there, inline in the class definition.

Alternatively, and closer to the style you have, you could define it in Library.cpp like this:

```
std​::​ostream &​operator ​<< (​std​::​ostream ​&out, ​const ​Library ​&lib) {
  return out << lib.something << ....;
}
```

Note that here you don't need to - and indeed can't - use the `friend` keyword. That's already taken care of.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I was able to properly implement the friend function.